# Vanilla Javascript find element with attribute on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to translate these few lines of jQuery based code into vanilla JS but I am struggling. Can someone please explain how to do it?

```
  function googletranslate() {
    $(".footer-toggle li, .select-lng li").on("click", function() {
      var rel = $(this).children("a").attr("rel");
      $(".goog-te-menu-frame:first").contents().find(".goog-te-menu2 .goog-te-menu2-item span:contains('" + rel + "')").get(0).click();
    });
  }

  setTimeout(googletranslate, 1000);
```

I know how to do a click event with javascript but im having a hard time finding the element (Just started learning).

```
<a href="#" rel="Spanish" title="Spanish">Spanish</a>
```

Basically when the link is clicked, it feeds through rel value to the hidden google translate widget, and simulates a click on the desired language.

Can someone explain how please? Would it be easier to use a select box and get the value from that instead?

Comment: you can use `document.querySelector` and `.querySelectorAll` to use complex css selectors like jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function googletranslate() {
  ['.footer-toggle li', '.select-lng li'].forEach(selector => {
    const elm = document.querySelector(selector);
    elm.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
  });

  function clickHandler(e) {
    const rel = e.target.querySelector('a').getAttribute('rel');
    const someGoogleSpan = document.querySelector(".goog-te-menu-frame:first")
      .querySelectorAll(".goog-te-menu2 .goog-te-menu2-item span:contains('" + rel + "')")[0];
    someGoogleSpan.click();
  }
}

setTimeout(googletranslate, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, look's promising but doesn't work. WebPack reported syntax errors, and after fixing those, it says clickHandler is not defined.

Comment: Ah! Well spotted. Getting a new error now, Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null, which probably means its failing to find the elements?

Comment: I'm using the selectors you posted in the question, if they don't reflect your HTML structure then you need to figure out which elements you want to select instead. For example `<div id="translate-button">Translate</div>` then select with `'#translate-button'`.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the html structure, but i think it will work I keep messing, thanks.

Comment: Seems its only finding the first li element, not all the LI elements

Answer (score 1):

```
document.querySelector('a[rel="Spanish"]')
```

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector